# Where has the source code of postreview Mercurial extension moved to?

Tags: mercurial, review-board

We use the postreview extension with Mercurial to post code reviews to reviewboard.  The [Mercurial docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ReviewboardExtension) point to a repository on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ccaughie/hgreviewboard).  Bitbucket has deprecated and deleted all Mercurial repositories as of late August, 2020.

Is there a new official home for the postreview extension from the original maintainers?

Comment: Not sure if the repository is now hosted somewhere but you can find its archived version here https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/ah/ahmed.chaudhary/mercurial-reviewboard.html

Answer (score 2):

The archive for the repository for the Reviewboard from the original authors is located here:

https://bitbucket-archive.softwareheritage.org/projects/cc/ccaughie/hgreviewboard.html